# Column store in data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, columnstore

I have a question about data warehousing and column oriented databases. In my project the company use a warehouse solution in visual studio SQL server, they have troubles with the performance when querying complex questions on large amount of data. I want to try to replace the database with a columnar based database. I know that you can "transform" a row oriented database in to more column based or use an open source database such as Vertica or Sybase IQ, i just wondering how it would fit in the warehouse? Do you have to have a star join schema in a warehouse or can you use the columnar approach instead, i realize this is kind of a stupid question but im just trying to understand it all before i start to explore the different databases and solutions. 
I know that SQL Server 2012 have a column store but i would like to try the other open source databases as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much of a performance problem?  Data warehouse queries are usually measured in minutes and hours, not seconds.  The most interesting queries require the database to go through lots of rows.

Comment: Im not sure exactly how much, just that it is a problem and they want to see what difference a column-oriented database can make. Im just confused since i just took a course in data warehousing and i learned to use the star join schema, can you just replace it with a columnoriented database?

Comment: What is a column oriented data base?  Can you point to a Wikipedia article?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS

Comment: Ok, if I understand correctly, you're not talking about changing table structure, you're talking about how the database engine actually stores the database bytes.  Sure, see if you get an improvement with a column oriented database engine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, i really appreciate it! Do you know if i can use for example Sybase IQ as a data warehouse solution? I read that its well suited for data warehousing but not if you can use it by itself or if you have to integrate it in some way in SQL server.

Comment: I don't want to have an extended discussion in the comments, but I've mostly used IBM's DB2 to build data warehouses, even though it's a row oriented database engine.  You can always ask additional detailed questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Neither Vertica nor Sybase IQ are open source... I think MonetDB is one of the few that is.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you have to have a star join schema in a warehouse or can you use the columnar approach instead?

The star join schema consists of the table definitions of your data warehouse.  The star schema, and similar schema, trade query performance for query flexibility.  Usually, query flexibility is more important than query performance in a data warehouse.

Based on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS) you linked to in your comments, a column oriented database engine stores the actual database bytes in column order, rather than the traditional row order of relational databases.

As the article says, this can improve disk access performance.

The star schema is how you define tables.  A column oriented database engine is concerned with how the database information is written to disk.  The two concepts have nothing to do with one another, except that they both apply to a data warehouse.

Keep your present data warehouse schema, and see if a column oriented database engine will improve query performance.

Comment: Now its starting to make sense :) Thanks a lot Gilbert! Im sure i will have thousands of more questions later but for now it seems clearer!

Comment: One thing - changing a DBMS engine is much more difficult than it looks, since every system implements SQL in different ways, and figuring out BI layer compatibility, etc, can be very challenging. You may be better off getting a *good* DBA to do some performance analysis of the queries and identify places to improve with better structures (indexing, etc) or hardware (disk I/O is usually a culprit).